# How to enter values in the Search Criteria field using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing a wierd issue where my script is not able to enter data in a Search Criteria screen.
**Note**: This is the same screen not a pop up window or a new window. Its just the navigation to some othe screen having the same webdriver instance

HTML:

```
<td class="dataCol requiredInput">

<input tabindex="1" maxlength="40" type="text" id="search_criteria" size="20" name="search_criteria" value="">

</td>
```

Code used by me :

```
LoginPage2.driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//input[@id='search_criteria']")
).sendKeys("test")
```

I am using Selenium 2.25.0

**Observation**: I dont face any issue in writing text values in the fields whose HTML syntax is as mentioned below:

```
<*td class="dataCol col02">
<*input id="00N20000001LwsL" maxlength="20" name="00N20000001LwsL" size="20" tabindex="6" type="text">
<*/td>
```

I am not sure if this is because of the HTML format or the way the code is built.

Kindly let me know if I am missing anything? I have tried `By.name` also

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific on the xpath, it's possible that multiple elements correspond to that same xpath. Perhaps try:

```
"//td[@class='dataCol requiredInput']/input[@tabindex='1' and @id='search_criteria']"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("ccc");
```